# Windows azure: Install wordpress in subfolder

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am playing with new Windows Azure which was released yesterday and I want to create a Umbraco website http://testwebsite.azurewebsites.net and a wordpress blog under the same website http://testwebsite.azurewebsites.net/blog/

But right now when I creating it, I can do it only for new website.

Is it possible with current websites implementation? Or I have to do some manual changes?

Maybe I can change some CNAME record... I need some simple solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use Gallery to create Widows Azure WebSite, then you will have option to use one kind of of package with one website. There is no way you can mix two package in one website directly from Portal based Gallery. So the experience you have seen is expected. To answer your question it is not possible to have two Gallery package set to one single website directly from portal/

Also with Windows Azure Websites (shared) you can not set CNAME record. The setting to use CNAME record is only with Windows Azure Websites (reserved).

Finally. I hope that you know that Umbraco is ASP.NET Based and Wordpress is PHP based websites package. So are you sure you want to have PHP based CMS site tucked with ASP.NET based CMS?

Comment: Thanks, I will try reserved instance... yes, I have a couple of websites which are ASP.NET+Wordpress and they are work fine.

Comment: Actually you can still use your the share instance however you would need to have your Umbraco and Worldpress put together locally and then upload it directly. Little complex but you sure can pull it off manually.